# Why was this suggested edit approved?

Tags: discussion

I am curious about how [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5263794) edit ended up as approved? 
It was the third suggested edit in a row by the same user (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5263659) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5263708)).

It shows as Rejected by two users and then approved by one, a 9 rep user account. I rolled it back and asked the user to stop suggesting edits, but I am more interested in why the system let it through after only one "Approve" and that even being from a low rep user. I thought you needed 2k rep to review edits?

Comment: Asker of the question him(her)self approved that suggested edit. In which case it gets approved immediately.

Comment: Aah, I see. I guess that makes sense. So was I wrong to roll it back then?

Comment: OP would be a better judge on a suggested edit, so I guess yes it should not have been rolled back.

Comment: The edit basically changes the entire question though and looks like an obvious attempt to answering it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The post owner is always given a binding review vote on suggested edits to their post. This is because the post owner is usually the one who knows best if an edit is appropriate for their post.

However in this case it's very clear that the edit changes the meaning of the question entirely and should not have been approved. Yes, the asker is in every right to exercise their binding review vote, however an asker is not allowed to completely change their own question to a different one with an edit either as it constitutes circumventing the system, so that rule takes precedence.

I'm starting to think that the system should consider individual review votes rather than entire review outcomes for the purpose of determining whether to ban a user from suggested edits. If **eight** reviewers all agree that several edits by the same user should be rejected, then we can probably trust their judgement on that one.

After all, robo-reviewers don't reject edits... right?

Comment: Also taking into account that all three suggested edits are basically the same. I don't know if the system is able to detect that though? It could perhaps at least easily detect that all three edits are on the same question?

Comment: @ivarni: That as well. I've once had to reject the same edit multiple times - only to be subverted by three robo-reviewers later (which makes me wonder if I should have disabled the editor's entire account instead since I couldn't disable just their editing abilities). It would be worth posting a feature request for the specific case you mention.

Comment: It's hard to formulate a good feature request without knowing what mechanisms are already in place, but I suppose I can describe the issue and let smarter minds figure out exactly what, if anything, can be done to detect things like this.

Comment: @ivarni: I can post it on your behalf if you prefer.

Comment: Lookig through this edtior's edit history, I see some rather poor edits.  [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4700191) is particularly concerning.  I don't know the subject matter so I can't tell how much has really changed, but between the comment and the quantity of changes, it looks like he completely rewrote the question.

Comment: @BoltClock If you could do that, I am sure you're able to formulate it better than me.

Comment: @psubsee2003: In the edit summary he says outright that he has to change the question just to suit his own bounty. And yet people approved it. I'm about to go and hit someone right now.

Comment: @BoltClock the approvals were dead wrong, but it actually looks like the OP answered **after** the question was changed.  And from [this commnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470241/how-to-relative-position-the-footer-in-the-bottom-of-the-page#comment35845369_10470241), I'm guessing the original "code/example" with the question (via an external link) no longer worked.  So he just decided to hijack the question.

Comment: @BoltClock agreed (or I wouldn't have brought it up)... the OP's involvement in the hijacked question was just odd.

Comment: @psubsee2003: I'll comment on the bountied answer and the OP's answer, and then I'll go and hit someone. Thanks for your help sussing all of this out.

Answer (score 2):

> I am more interested in why the system let it through after only one "Approve"

Asker of the question him(her)self approved that suggested edit in which case only one vote completes the review.

[Reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work):

> The owner of a post may cast a binding vote to accept or reject any
>   modification of their post.

Comment: Thanks, I guess with a little more digging I should have been able to figure that one out :)